# make a task list using java, to add, edit, remove or exit from the program using switch statements and loops

Tags: java

Create a program that allows a user to add, remove, edit, and list to-do items by presenting the user with a menu similar to the following:

Please choose an option:
(1) Add a task.
(2) Remove a task.
(3) Update a task.
(4) List all tasks.
(0) Exit.

If the user chooses to add a task, the program should prompt for a description of the task and add it to the collection of tasks. If the user chooses to remove a task, the program should ask the user which item to remove and remove it from the collection of tasks. If the user chooses to update a task, the program should ask which task will be updated and for a new description of the task.  The program should loop until the user chooses to exit.

```
package com.vanderkooi1.Project1;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String choice;

    do {
        //Splash screen with options
        System.out.println("Please Choose an option");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("(1) Add a task ");
        System.out.println("(2) Remove a task ");
        System.out.println("(3) Update a task ");
        System.out.println("(4) List all tasks ");
        System.out.println("(0) Exit ");

        switch (choice) {
        case "1":
            System.out.println("Add a task ");
            choice = input.nextLine();
            break;
        case "2":
            System.out.println("Remove a task");
            choice = input.nextLine();
            break;
        case "3":
            System.out.println("Update a task");
            choice = input.nextLine();
            break;
        case "4":
            System.out.println("List all tasks");
            choice = input.nextLine();
            break;
        }
    }

    while (choice > 0) {
        System.out.println("Exit");
    }
```

my do statement says there is an unknown token error and my while statement has unknown class 'choice'.

Comment: welcome to stack overflow. please fix your indentation, so the code gets displayed properly!

Comment: Hey! Did you end up finishing this To Do List program?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a brace after the final one. Reformatting the code makes the discrepancy clear.

Also the `while` condition needs to be connected to the `do`, as per:

```
do {
  // something
while (condition);
```

Not:

```
do {
   // something
}

while (somethingElse) {
   // more things
}
```

Furthermore your `while` condition is performing a numeric check on a String.

Finally none of this code is happening within a method, but in a static context.

This is my best guess as to what the code was originally intended to do - compiles, but has not been run. Hope it helps:

```
package com.vanderkooi1.Project1;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main().myMethod();
    }

    public void myMethod() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String choice = null;

        do {
            //Splash screen with options
            System.out.println("Please Choose an option");
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("(1) Add a task ");
            System.out.println("(2) Remove a task ");
            System.out.println("(3) Update a task ");
            System.out.println("(4) List all tasks ");
            System.out.println("(0) Exit ");

            switch (choice) {
            case "1":
                System.out.println("Add a task ");
                choice = input.nextLine();
                break;
            case "2":
                System.out.println("Remove a task");
                choice = input.nextLine();
                break;
            case "3":
                System.out.println("Update a task");
                choice = input.nextLine();
                break;
            case "4":
                System.out.println("List all tasks");
                choice = input.nextLine();
                break;
            }
        }
        while ( Integer.parseInt(choice) > 0);

        System.out.println("Exit");
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess I don't understand that statement, I want to do the switch statements until the user enters 0...you only need one do and one while statement correct?

Comment: Updated my answer and suggested rewrite. Confusion is between String representation of a number and an actual number that can be compared with another number.

Answer (score 0):

package sssss;

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    String choice = null;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please Choose an option");
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("(1) Add a task ");
    System.out.println("(2) Remove a task ");
    System.out.println("(3) Update a task ");
    System.out.println("(4) List all tasks ");
    System.out.println("(0) Exit ");
    choice = input.nextLine();
    do {
        //Splash screen with options
        System.out.println("Please Choose an option");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("(1) Add a task ");
        System.out.println("(2) Remove a task ");
        System.out.println("(3) Update a task ");
        System.out.println("(4) List all tasks ");
        System.out.println("(0) Exit ");

        switch (choice) {

        case "1":
            System.out.println("Add a task ");
            choice = input.nextLine();
            break;
        case "2":
            System.out.println("Remove a task");
            choice = input.nextLine();
            break;
        case "3":
            System.out.println("Update a task");
            choice = input.nextLine();
            break;
        case "4":
            System.out.println("List all tasks");
            choice = input.nextLine();
            break;
        }
    }
    while ( Integer.parseInt(choice) > 0);

    System.out.println("Exit");
}
}
```

Comment: This code gives me the same problem as my first one, even with the extra } added to the end

Comment: you can do this in better way but i try to stick with your way

Comment: neither code works I get a bunch of class errors on both..actually that's my bad my settings were off

Comment: just a quick question..if I want to send for example my add task through a method would I place the method call between the choice = input.nextLine(); and break; statement? so the tasks will store and can be edited and removed?

Comment: yes you can i prefer to put it as a call back before the choice=input.nextLine()